# Определить являются ли первые пять символов каждой строки файла цифрами

Tags: pascal

Дан текстовый файл f не пустой. Определить являются ли первые пять символов каждой строки файла цифрами. Если да то установить, является ли их произведение четным числом. Работает некорректно. На разных вариантах строк. Примеры (22222- работает нормально. п222р-ошибка, тут должно по идеи удалять эту строку и дальше обрабатывать файл)

```
 program project1;

const
ZNAK = ['.', ',', ':', ';', '!', '?', '-', ' ','/'];
CHECK = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
var
t:Text;
s,pyt: String;
h:char;
i,j,f,n, LenS, dlinc : Integer;
begin
f:=0;
n:=1;
dlinc := 0;
pyt:= 't.txt';
writeln('Файл',pyt);
Assign(t,pyt);
Reset(t);

while not Eof(t) do
begin
     readln(t,s);
     LenS := Length(S);

     for i := 1 to LenS do
         if not (S[i] in ZNAK) then
         begin
              Inc(dlinc);
              if (i = LenS) or (S[i + 1] in ZNAK) then
              begin
                   if dlinc >= 5 then
                   begin

                        for j:= 1 to 5 do
                        begin
                             h:=s[j];
                             if h in CHECK then
                             begin
                                  val(h,f);
                                  n:=f*n;
                             end
                             else delete(s,1,dlinc);
                        end;
                   if n mod 2 = 0 then write(' Chetnoe = ',n)
                   else write (' Necnetnoe = ',n); //Проверка на четноесть нечетноесть
                   n:=1;
                   delete(s,1,dlinc);
                   end



                   else
                   begin
                   delete(s,1,dlinc);
                   dlinc := 0;
                   writeln('dlina menshe 5i = ', s);
                   end;
                   end;
              end;
         end;
Close(t);
Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Опять? Вопрос лучше не стал. Где в условии что-то говорится о знаках препинания и об удалении части строки?

Answer (score 0):

Писал "на коленке" могут быть неточности.

```
...
while not EOF(t) do
begin
  ReadLn(t, s);
  s := Copy(s, 1, 5);
  val(s, Number, Code);
  if Code = 0 then
  begin
    prod := 1;
    for i := 0 to 5 do
      prod := prod * (Ord(s[i]) - Ord('0'));
    if prod mod 2 = 0 then
    WriteLn('Prod is even: ', prod)
    else
    WriteLn('Prod is not even: ', prod);
  end 
  else WriteLn('Invalid value: ', s);
end;
...
```

Comment: "является ли их *произведение* четным ..."

Comment: Исправил. Хотя это мог сделать Denis  сам.

Comment: `prod := 0;` - ??

Comment: У меня ощущение, что Вы преподаватель, а я ученик. Естественно там должна быть единица. Мне кажется задавший вопрос такие мелочи и сам должен увидеть, тем более в его вопросе там именно единица. А своим ответом я просто указал на вариант решения и пометил, что выполнил на коленке и не проверял в среде. Вы через чур придираетесь.

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно проверять на четность все произведение, достаточно чтобы один из множителей являлся четным (если хоть один множитель равен нулю, то и все произведение будет равно нулю; считать ли его четным - нужно уточнять):

```
program FirstFive;
const
  fin = 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\in.txt';
  len = 5;

function IsEven(var n: integer): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
  k: integer;
begin
  k := 10;

  for i := 1 to len - 1 do
    begin
      if (((n div k) mod 10) mod 2 = 0) then
        begin
          result := True;
          Exit;
        end;

      k := k * 10;
    end;

  result := False;
end;

var
  f: Text;
  s: string;
  n: integer;
  line: integer;

begin
  Assign(f, fin);
  Reset(f);

  WriteLn('Номер   Первые 5 чисел   Четность   Строка в файле');

  line := 0;
  while not EoF(f) do
    begin
      ReadLn(f, s);
      Inc(line);
      try
        n := StrToInt(Copy(s, 1, len));
        if (pos('0', Copy(s, 1, len)) > 0) then
          begin
            WriteLn(line:5, 'True':17, '0':11, '   ', s);
            continue;
          end;
        if (IsEven(n)) then
          WriteLn(line:5, 'True':17, 'Even':11, '   ', s)
        else
          WriteLn(line:5, 'True':17, 'Odd':11, '   ', s);
      except
        WriteLn(line:5, 'False':17, '-':11, '   ', s);
      end;
    end;

  Close(f);
end.
```

Вывод:

```
Номер   Первые 5 чисел   Четность   Строка в файле
    1             True       Even   12345-jkhdfg
    2             True       Even   22222l;kopkjoi
    3            False          -   jknjk
    4            False          -   54lkjlkj
    5            False          -   5;;l4
    6            False          -   2222jnjk
    7             True       Even   25525ojiojio
    8             True          0   04440mn
    9             True       Even   98745jnjbhj
   10             True        Odd   13579
   11            False          -
```